# ocamldoc not properly displaying parameter names or description with @param

Tags: ocaml, documentation, documentation-generation, code-documentation, ocamldoc

Simply put, let us say I have the following OCaml file called `test.ml`:

```ml
(**
    [Test] is a sample module for showing the problem I am having with @ tags with OCamlDoc
*)

(**
    [id] is the identity function. For any argument [x], [id x] is [x].
    @param x The argument, which will be returned
    @return The argument [x]
*)
let id (x: 'a): 'a = x
```

If I run the command `ocamldoc -html -all-params -colorize-code test.ml` to get the documentation for the `Test` module, I get the following result:

[image: documentation]

As can be seen, for the parameter information, it puts `()` as the name of the parameter and does not include a description for the parameter for some reason.

I am unsure why the parameter name and description are not properly showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write `let id x = x` the display is correct:

[image]

The problem is that ocamldoc will not display `@param` if you provide a tag that doesn't match a named argument but it's not able to extract a named argument from `(id : type)`.

This is a known bug but sadly nobody touched it so... https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/issues/8804

Comment: I see. It is unfortunate that it has not been touched and has even been closed. As per @octachron, I will be looking into `odoc`.

Answer (score 2):

As ocamldoc's part-time maintainer, there are very few reasons to still use ocamldoc when odoc is available, even more so when writing new documentation.

Ocamldoc's handling of param tag is far too complex for its own good: ocamldoc tries to peek at the definition of the function and only accepts param tag that matches the argument that it can recognize. Here, it fails on explicit type annotation.

Comment: I will definitely look into `odoc` as an alternative. Thank you!